# SQL - Mathematical (Min - Max Normalisation)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, math, sqlcommand

I want to normalization operation in my code. I have a SQL - Server table, it has 3 columns; first column has single words, second column has single words, third column has integer values. I researched it and I thought I should do a sql query rather than writing a complex C# code. I have a DataGridView and it look like that (Example 1);

```
           Column 1          Column 2
         ------------------------------
          hello my             4500
          crazy day            3200
          such a               2885
          new coder            1010
```

Normalization formula : ((Value / Max Value) * 100)

Problem : It works good in first step, after normalization operation my DataGridView looks like that;

```
           Column 1          Column 2
         ------------------------------
          hello my             %100
          crazy day            %71.11
          such a               %64.11
          new coder            %22.44
```

But when I upload other links to the system like that (Example 2);

```
           Column 1          Column 2
         ------------------------------
          maybe today          2560
          it mine              1405
          the world            800
          welcome there        400
```

It returns my normalized values like that, because it takes maximum value 4500 everytime;

```
           Column 1          Column 2
         ------------------------------
          maybe today          %56.88
          it mine              %31.22
          the world            %17.77
          welcome there        %8.88
```

But, I want it to be considered in itself. When I upload new link, it should find the maximum value in links and return normalization values according to that. So, my DataGridView should look like that;

```
           Column 1          Column 2
         ------------------------------
          maybe today          2560
          it mine              1405
          the world            800
          welcome there        400




           Column 1          Column 2
         ------------------------------
          maybe today          %100
          it mine              %54.88
          the world            %31.25
          welcome there        %15.62
```

It's my code;

```
   string myCommand = "SELECT c1, c2, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), c3) / (SELECT MAX(c3) FROM myTableName)) * 100) AS normalizedc3 FROM myTableName WHERE c1='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c2='" + sr[mssi2] + "' OR c2='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c1='" + sr[msii2] + "'";
```

It's my second code for it;

```
    string myCommand = "select c1, c2, c3 / m.max_c3 * 100 normalizedvalue from myTableName inner join (select convert(float, max(c3)) max_c3 from myTableName) m on 1 = 1 WHERE c1='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c2='" + sr[mssi2] + "' OR c2='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c1='" + sr[mssi2] + "'";
```

It's my full code;

```
            for (int mssi1 = 0; mssi1 < sr.Length; mssi1++)
            {
                for (int mssi2 = mssi1 + 1; mssi 2< sr.Length; mssi2++)
                {
                    string myCommand = "SELECT c1, c2, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), c3) / (SELECT MAX(c3) FROM myTableName)) * 100) AS normalizedc3 FROM myTableName WHERE c1='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c2='" + sr[mssi2] + "' OR c2='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c1='" + sr[mssi2] + "'";
                    SqlDataAdapter sadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mc, conection);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sadapter.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        bool removeMyDup = dgv2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().AsEnumerable().Any(x =>
                            Convert.ToString(x.Cells["Column1"].Value).Split(' ')[0] == row["c1"].ToString() &&
                            Convert.ToString(x.Cells["Column1"].Value).Split(' ')[1] == row["c2"].ToString() &&
                            Convert.ToInt32(x.Cells["Column2"].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(row["c3"])
                        );
                        if (!removeMyDup)
                            dgv2.Rows.Add(row["c1"].ToString() + " " + row["c2"].ToString(), row["c3"]);
                    }
                 }
            }
```

Note 1 : 4500 is not my maximum value, it's only an example. My maximum value is 1400000 and my minimum value is 10. But everytime I upload different links the system. Maximum and minimum number always change...

Note 2 : If you want I can share all of my code, please leave a comment for it.

How should I fix it in a sql command or c# code, I'm waiting for your helps. Thank you.

Comment: you should probably group each set of data by an ID or some thing indicator of each set (for example group by link)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary How should I do it, can you give an example?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary but the data is unclear. Different loading every time. There is no specific set.

Comment: If you don't want to select the max from the table and instead select the max from the current result set, one way is to just use a window function, like `MAX(col) OVER()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like add a BATCH_ID column to your table, and each set of data that you add gets a unique BATCH_ID. Then your query can become something like:

```
string myCommand = 
"SELECT c1, c2, 
((CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), c3) / (SELECT MAX(c3) FROM myTableName b where b.BATCH_ID = A.BATCH_ID)) * 100) AS normalizedc3 
FROM myTableName a 
WHERE c1='" + mfa[msi] + "' AND c2='" + msa[mssi] + "' OR c1='" + msa[mssi] + "' AND c2='" + mfa[msi] + "'";
```

If you mean just the max of the resultset then you can use Gordon's answer:

```
string myCommand = 
"SELECT c1, c2, 
c3 * 100.0 / max(c3) over () as normalizedc3
FROM myTableName a 
WHERE c1='" + mfa[msi] + "' AND c2='" + msa[mssi] + "' OR c1='" + msa[mssi] + "' AND c2='" + mfa[msi] + "'";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188566/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-sql-mathematical-min-max-normalisation). If the code doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to improve the [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SQL query, then you can get the values you want as:

```
select t.*,
       column2 * 100.0 / max(column2) over () as normalized_value
from t;
```

If you add a `where` clause, the max used for normalization is the maximum of the data being selected.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=008b57ee46253b539dc1a6d57c1039c0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: So how should I use it without where? I need where clause.

Comment: @ImaNewCoder . . . So add the `where` clause.  Does it do what you want?

Comment: Sorry but I'm new at this job. Sometimes I don't understand someone's code. :) I understand, I should select my all table with over (), but what is the meaning of c2? My integers values are in c3. Should I generate a new column?

Comment: I tried your code but it returns 100 for all values.

Comment: I added my other code, if you want you can check it.

Comment: @ImaNewCoder . . . You are doing something wrong.  The code works.  I just added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried this; string myCommand = "select c1, c2, c3 * 100.0 / max(c3) over () as normalized_value FROM myTableName a WHERE c1='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c2='" + sr[mssi2] + "' OR c2='" + sr[mssi1] + "' AND c1='" + sr[mssi2] + "'";